# send sms j2me appear promt message

Tags: java-me, wma

When I am sending sms via j2me application, before message sent it appears question for can I use internet to sent message. Is it possible to exit this question to not appear?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you Accessing HTTP & SMS API. For using such API you need to signed your Java ME Application. For Signed a the Java ME Application, you need to purchase Signing Certificate from VeriSign or Thawte Site by paying the Fees.

Plesae visit this [link](http://www.verisign.com/in/)

For VeriSign's certificate, they costs 20K per certificate.

Comment: Is there another solution (without signed Java ME Application) for sending sms via j2me app and to not appear question before sent sms?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible as they are restricted APIs. However you may try Self Certified Application. Search on Google for it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can skip the prompt but your application must be signed. However, even if your application is signed, on some devices, the prompt will still appear once. This usually (or always) occurs on the session's first use of the Wireless Messaging API. This happens because the access to this API is set to something like "Ask first time."

If your app is signed, you can manually set the access to the wireless network settings to (something like) "Always allow." If it is set to (something like) this, the prompt will not appear.

For apps that are not signed, the option "Always allow" is not available. However, on most devices, the next best option is available: "Ask first time."

Well, the bad thing is, you are going to set it manually. The good thing, however, is that you are not going spend so much money just to set it to "Ask first time." :D

Answer (score -1):

J2ME by the platform design have the drawbacks in which users of the applications are asked to  select yes or no for any attempt to use any of the secure API's. Some devices gives this alerts in such a way which will make the end user to think if he should go ahead or stop it there. By digitally signing the application, one can reduce the alerts to levels depending on the device KVM implementation and the number of secure APIs in use.

In some device having Symbian OS Feature Pack 1, the prompts continue even if the code is signed.
This behavior of J2ME makes the applications less developer friendly and less user friendly. I think this is a wrong strategy and model adopted by SUN. There is some thing called Verified by Java in which you can get your application signed using a certificate which will make the application work seamlessly and without prompts in the end user device but unfortunately the process of getting that certification is expensive and not practical. The only advantage of J2ME platform is that it allows less chances of virus or malware code to be executed on the end user device. I think the trade off between security and ease of user use is not worked well and that is the reason we don't see very good apps in J2ME.

In contrast, Android for example, lets the user see all the permissions prior to installation of the app and the user is not bothered at run time when those secure API are used. That is the reason we see millions of apps there and not in J2ME. We can always say this approach had led to many malware types of applications in the end android user device but that is how it goes, people need to have smooth apps running and are happy with them.